# Meaning and origin of "после сытного обеда полагается поспать"

Tags: phrase

I have been hearing often the phrase "после сытного обеда по закону архимеда полагается поспать". I take that it is quite a familiar saying to most Russians. I wanted to find out more about this saying - where it is written by Archimedes, and why/how this saying became popular in Russia (if that is known). If anyone knows or can find, I would appreciate it. Google searches in Russian turn up blogs about food.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Это шутка. Архимед об обеде ничего не писал, такого "закона Архимеда" не существует.:) Просто имя Архимед хорошо рифмуется со словом "обед". Это старый стишок, который довольно популярен в среде тинэйджеров.

It is a joke. Archimedes about a lunch wrote nothing, such "Archimedes's law" doesn't exist. :) Simply the name Archimedes in Russian is well rhymed with the word "lunch". It is an old rhyme which is quite popular among teenagers.

Есть ещё один похожий стишок: "После сытного обеда, по закону Архимеда, чтобы жиром не заплыть, полагается курить".

Answer (score 10):

That's just a childish rhyme. Yet another variant "*После сытного обеда вытри руки об соседа*" doesn't mention Archimedes at all. Both are quite old and it seems that no one remembers when they first appear.